# flip the UIImageView using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

create 2 UIImageView .

create one UIView containerView to contain UIImageView

Show frontImageView in the beginning for 5s.

after flip, show backImageView then again FrontImageView .I need in Viewdidload not while clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIView.transition` and change the image on completion handler

```
let animation:UIViewAnimationOptions = someCondition ? .transitionFlipFromLeft :.transitionFlipFromRight
UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: n, options:animation, animations: {
    //Do something
}) { (isAnimated:Bool) in
    //Do something
    //Change the image
    //imageView.image = ....
}
```

Comment: I HAVE EDITED MYQUESTION.PLEASE CHECK.AND I NEED IN OBJECTIVE-C

Comment: this function also available in objc, in fact it is objc function. you can write this code in viewdidload. I hope you need flip repeat after some seconds, is it?